# Extracting .htm files from SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have inherited a SQL Server 2005 installation with some .htm files which I need to extract as the originals are missing. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Just copy the .htm files, then you can pretend that the first ones you had were the 'originals'  o_O

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by "some .htm files." If these are created as part of a SSRS report, then yes, you can get the entire .rdl (Report definition language) which is the definition of the structure of the report.

In some circumstances, an SSRS author may add additional files to be called by the report (such as a style sheet or images.) These are stored in the file system on the server, usually in the reporting services directories: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179314%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Let us know more details about what you are looking for... 
Jamie F